# You can find me everywhere

Tags: riddle, word

I contain a tin ion

And you cannot find me in a crayon

---

But don't worry little peon

You can find me in a swan

You can find me in a heron

You can even find me in a fawn

---

You need me to move

Without me you will just be like a puddle of goo

---

You should not let me touch others like me

I promise you, I'm worse than an angry bee

---

Beware my wrath,

It's worse than an icy cold bath

But on the upside - I can help you do math!

---

To get your answer accepted you need to get the word and explain what most of the lines/groups of lines refer to

**Hint #1**:

> The pain the fourth stanza talks about happens mostly to older people

Comment: Is a hint needed?

Comment: i'm not able to think of anything that fits more than two stanzas, so ... yes? :)

Comment: @Rubio Added a hint, I'm trying not to give too much away at a time though=)

Comment: is it calcium ?

Comment: No; I'll reveal a pretty big hint before I sleep though

Comment: bones was my first guess but to fit in last stanza as 'calculus' i moved to think of calcium :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you ...

> A bone

I contain a tin ion

> Bones contain some trace measure of tin, and possibly stannous flouride, from some random articles a little Googling found me.

And you cannot find me in a crayon

> well, no - crayons have no bones.

But don't worry little peon
You can find me in a swan
You can find me in a heron
You can even find me in a fawn

> ... all of which have bones.

You need me to move
Without me you will just be like a puddle of goo

> Muscles provide movement by pulling against bones (in humans, mammals, etc)., and without a skeleton we would not have the essential structure and shape of our bodies.

You should not let me touch others like me
I promise you, I'm worse than an angry bee

> Wearing away of cartilage in joints, such that bones rub against each other, is a cause of great pain (arthritis, back pain, etc.), most notably in older persons as per the hint.

Beware my wrath,
It's worse than an icy cold bath

> breaking a bone leaves it first very numb, and then in great pain?

But on the upside - I can help you do math!

> Um...  a stretch here, but two possibilities come to my mind:
>  1. you can count on your fingers, which owe their shape to their slender bones, or
>  2. more likely, dice ("bones") get used frequently in statistics / probability.

Comment: Yes, you got it! Well done

Comment: I guessed it before the hint, but wasn't confident enough in my guess before the hint made it all but certain.  curious what you actually had in mind for that last line :)

Comment: Your #2 possibility for the last line was correct=)